# what is needed to run and install software-center?

Tags: software-center, lxde, linaro

i've got a completely stripped lubuntu called linaro (lxde desktop, H8 arm processor, cubietruckplus/cubieboard5) on my console, since the hardware is custom i can't install ubuntu the way i'm used.
what libaries are needed for software center? i have installed synaptic and xapian, but the software center tells me there's something wrong with my location?
i tried following the installation for mint and it installs, but it's not working.

Comment: You need to actually give errors.

Comment: [Edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/823626/edit) your question and tell us what are those `something wrong with your location` it said.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try finding all the dependencies of the software centre.  Here is how you find all the dependencies:

```
apt-cache depends software-center
```

If I do that on my system (16.04) I see the following output:

```
software-center
  Depends: <python:any>
    python:i386
    python
  Depends: iso-codes
  Depends: app-install-data
  Depends: aptdaemon
  Depends: software-center-aptdaemon-plugins
  Depends: humanity-icon-theme
  Depends: gir1.2-glib-2.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-gmenu-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-webkit2-4.0
  Depends: gvfs-backends
    gvfs-backends:i386
  Depends: python-gi
  Depends: python-gi-cairo
  Depends: python-xapian
    python-xapian1.3
  Depends: python-apt
  Depends: python-aptdaemon
  Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  Depends: python-dbus
  Depends: python-defer
  Depends: python-lxml
  Depends: policykit-1
    policykit-1:i386
 |Depends: policykit-1-gnome
    lxpolkit
    mate-polkit
  Depends: <policykit-1-kde>
  Depends: python-xdg
  Depends: ubuntu-sso-client
  Depends: python-piston-mini-client
  Depends: oneconf
 |Depends: python-oneconf
  Depends: oneconf
  Depends: python-debtagshw
  Conflicts: <gnome-app-install>
  Recommends: lsb-release
  Recommends: apt-xapian-index
  Recommends: update-notifier
    gnome-packagekit
  Recommends: software-properties-gtk
  Recommends: sessioninstaller
  Recommends: xz-utils
    xz-utils:i386
  Replaces: <gnome-app-install>
    software-center
```

And here is what one gets for lubuntu:

```
> apt-cache depends lubuntu-software-center

lubuntu-software-center
  Depends: python
  Depends: python
  Depends: python-apt
 |Depends: python-gi
  Depends: python-gobject
  Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  Depends: gir1.2-notify-0.7
  Depends: python-pysqlite2
  Depends: python-aptdaemon
  Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
  Depends: python-xdg
  Depends: app-install-data
```

I suspect you would need to install all the packages listed there to get Software centre to work properly.

[Edited to add the output for lubuntu's version of software centre.]

Comment: seems i tried to install the wrong software center. lubuntu-software-center worked right away thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

To show the dependencies of the Ubuntu Software Center (*software-center*) open the terminal and type:

```
apt-cache showpkg software-center
```

To show the dependencies of Lubuntu Software Center (*lubuntu-software-center*):

```
apt-cache showpkg lubuntu-software-center
```

Comment: seems i tried to install the wrong software center. lubuntu-software-center worked right away thanks guys